# How to import android library from GitHub to eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-gradle-plugin, android-library, eclipse-adt

How to add gradle library in android project.

We download the project from github.
https://github.com/michael-rapp/ChromeLikeTabSwitcher

We follow these step but it showing the error.

1. Import the library folder from above zip as Android project.
2. It create folder of main with blank src, so we copy the data from folder java
   to src.
3. After refresh in eclips it's showing error in src folder of functions.

We also import example folder and follow the same step as above, but no luck.

Let me know if i do something wrong or can you test this library on your eclips.

Thanks..

Comment: Use Android-Studio

Comment: I think it's also possible in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Download archive **android.jar** from *https://jar-download.com/download-handling.php* in Downloads folder. Then connect it to android project in Eclipse by means of project Properties/Java build path. That is all.

This will be the universal solution for all your eclipse android projects while android.jar is in Downloads folder.